# Simulink 3D lookup table

Tags: matlab, simulink, solver, lookup-tables

I have a system of three nonlinear equations with eight unknowns.  I'm currently setting each equation equal to a desired value and then using Matlab's fsolve (a numerical solver) to find a solution.  Instead of running fsolve in real-time, I'd like to pre-compute solutions for a specific set of values to which I set the equations equal.

Pursuant that goal, I've run the solver over a set of values and created a 3D matrix (N x N x N) which I've attempted to load into eight Simulink 3-D lookup tables, Direct Lookup Table n-D block, so I can fetch each of the eight solved unknowns.  It's my understanding the inputs to this block should work the same way I would reference an element in my 3-D array:  table(x,y,z) but I'm constantly getting Simulink table input out-of-range errors.  I've confirmed the inputs are within the table size, so I'm not sure what's wrong.

This isn't the most elegant implementation, so I'm open to better solutions.  Ideally, I'd like to have a Simulink lookup that takes three inputs and returns a vector of the eight solved unknowns, or even better, can do some type of linear interpolation between the three lookup values to return an approximate solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Which `Breakpoint Specification` method have you used in the block(s)?

Comment: I'm actually not using breakpoints since it's a Direct Lookup Table n-D block.   If I switch to a n-D Lookup Table, then I would have to specify them...which I actually don't know how to do.  Is there an easy way to do that for a 3-D matrix that's 201x201x201 in size?

Comment: What are the input values when the error occurs? (Have you accounted for the the fact that the Direct Lookup table uses zero-based counting?)

Comment: Yes, I believe I have.  I plotted the signals (with the block set back to warn instead of error) and at no point do the values appear to exceed my dimensions.  I'm stumped.

Comment: Can you upload (as an edit to your question) an image of the error and the data when the error occurs?